# Twitter api is not returning email address with user info array

Tags: php, twitter-oauth

I want to make an authentication process where user can login using twitter api. I have used [Abraham's PHP library](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) for doing it. It's returning everything except user email. I have passed optional parameters like this -

```
$parameters['include_email'] = true;
$parameters['skip_status'] = true;
$parameters['include_entities'] = true;
```

And also has checked "Request email addresses from users" in Permissions Tab of my App. But it's not returning any email address. Now can anyone helps me for following queries -

1) I am sure that there is a way to do. [please check this link](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials). Then what's my fault? which thing I need to change?

2) Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Just to make sure, did you get your application whitelisted? 

From https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/log-in-with-twitter.html#request-user-email-address:

> Requesting a user’s email address requires your application to be whitelisted by Twitter. To request access, please visit https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform.

Comment: yes, it's whitelisted. Otherwise, I will not find this checkbox "Request email addresses from users"

Comment: I see. I saw that checkbox on apps I never requested this for, so I wasn't sure if it's always there.

Comment: I have contacted with their support center & they have informed me about it.

Comment: @Jobayer, are you able to get the user email address?

Comment: no, do you have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

For Any one see this problem in twitter Api As I Faced

The Solution Is :

```
$parameters['include_email'] = "true";
```

Twitter Api need value as string not bool it's very strange behavior but it work